# Python script import error `failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied` with hplip

Tags: linux, printing, python

I have been installing locally the latest hplip 3.6.11 (HP Linux Imaging and Printing) for two computers that run on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The general installation procedure is described [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html). The whole procedure finished seamlessly for one machine but not for another one. I would like to pinpoint the cause of this failure and complete the installation.

#### Incident description

The step where one computer fails is when using `hp-setup` to configure the printer. `hp-setup` is a symbolic link to a Python script. On both machines, this file has the same attributes:

```
ll -Z $(realpath `which hp-setup`)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 38026 Mar  1 08:10 /usr/share/hplip/setup.py*
```

In the failing computer, launching `hp-setup` throws an import error

```
Please make sure your printer is connected and powered on at this time.
Do you want to setup printer in GUI mode? (u=GUI mode*, i=Interactive mode) : i
Running 'hp-setup  -i' command....
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/hp-setup", line 48, in <module> from base import device, utils, tui, models, module, services, os_utils
File "/usr/share/hplip/base/device.py", line 42, in <module> from . import status
File "/usr/share/hplip/base/status.py", line 33, in <module> import cupsext
ImportError: libgpg-error.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
error: hp-setup failed. Please run hp-setup manually.
```

Concerning `cupsext` (in the most recent call), in both computers the build directory of hplip contains `./hplip-3.16.11/prnt/cupsext/` that contains `cupsext.h` and `cupsext.o`. Conditions are equal here.

The requisite shared object lives in the same location `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.10.0` in both computers. The `ll -Z` shows same attributes and permissions, again.

Concerning the suggestion to run the script manually, it does not matter whether `hp-setup` is run by a script or manually. Actually, I get the same error if I launch one other script `hp-plugin`.

Also, the fact that installation script went this far means that all dependency and conflict issues have been ironed out.

This error is repeatable. If I remove the build/object directory manually and re-install from scratch, it occurs again. Note that the installation script itself has a rule to clean existing versions of hplip, including the one I had just installed with the same script.

With this evidence I searched possible causes of this error around the internet.

#### HPLIP diagnostics and troubleshooting tips

`hp-check` cannot only find what `hp-setup` has not accomplished, which is consistent. Then, the [troubleshoot documentation](http://hplipopensource.com/node/224) does not seem to cover this error.

#### SELinux permission, security contexts and the like

This cause is suggested, for example, [here](http://www.haidongji.com/2011/04/03/selinux-and-failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object-error/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502156/what-are-possible-causes-of-failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object-operatio).
I do acknowledge that [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) issues are far beyond my experience and expertise.
However, the `ll -Z` command above shows that the SELinux tag `?` is the same for same files in both computers. So the SELinux spoor does not quite isolate the issue.

#### Question

What can be the reason for a Python script

- to throw an import error
- to fail to map a segment from a `so` file
- to encounter a permission denied

at the same time?

**Disclaimer** I has already lodged a question on this error in the past https://askubuntu.com/questions/743164/hplip-update-cannot-install-plugin, but I cannot quite recall which workaround or heavenly twist worked then. The description of this one incident is much more thorough since it isolates the problem within a scripting and library issue, which is independent of Ubuntu.